# How to use multiple @Onetoone & @OnetoMany annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm newbie in Spring boot and making first time an experimental app. This app consist on 3 classes / tables:

Account:

- has an account numbers that can be call by JournalEntryDetail, so I get @onetoone relation

JournalEntryMaster:

- can have many JournalEntryDetail
- I use here @OnetoMany annotation

JournalEntryDetail:

- can have one JournalEntryMaster
- Foreign key to Account, as Account number should be equal b/w JournalEntDetail & Account table

I get an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation 
of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not 
allowed on a @OneToOne property: com.accounts.entity.JournalEntryMaster.jvNumber
```

I can understand what does error means but unfortunately I did not find solution, so I came here. Any one could advise will be appreciated.

I copy entities hereunder:

accountnumber

```
public class Account {
@Id
@GeneratedValue

@Column(name="account_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="account_number")
private Long accountNumber;

@Column(name="account_name")
private String accountName;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="dr_or_credit")
private DrOrCrSide drOrCrSide;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="account_type")
private AccountType accountType;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private JournalEntryDetail journalEntryDetail;
```

JournalEntryMaster

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class JournalEntryMaster {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@Column(name="jv_number")
private Long jvNumber;

@Column(name="jv_master_date")
private Date Date;

@Column(name="jv_reference_no")
private String ReferenceNo;

@Column(name="memo")
private String Memo;

@Column(name="posted")
private boolean Posted;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = JournalEntryDetail.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<JournalEntryDetail> journalEntryDetail = new HashSet<>();
}
```

JourEntryDetail

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString

public class JournalEntryDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="account_number")
private Long accountNumber;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="jv_detail_drcr")
private DrOrCrSide DrCr;

@Column(name="amount")
private Double Amount;

@Column(name="memo")
private String Memo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "jv", referencedColumnName = "id")
private JournalEntryMaster jv;

@JoinColumn(name = "account_fk_jv", referencedColumnName = "account_number")
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Account.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Account account_number;

@JoinColumn(name = "jvnumber_fk", referencedColumnName = "jv_number")
@OneToOne(targetEntity = JournalEntryMaster.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private JournalEntryMaster jvNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
public class JournalEntryMaster {
...
@OneToOne <-- remove this annotation
@Column(name="jv_number")
private Long jvNumber;
```

You use `Long` for the `jvNumber`. If this is just a database column and its not related to an entity, don't use `@OneToOne`. You can remove the annotation and your error `@Column(s) not  allowed on a @OneToOne property: com.accounts.entity.JournalEntryMaster.jvNumber` will disappear.

On the other hand, if it is related to an entity, you have to use `JoinColumn` instead of `Column` and use your `EntityClass` instead of `Long`.

Comment: JournalEntityMaster is the master class & related to entity. I believe I already done what you advise in JournalEntityDetail class

Comment: I think you mean `JournalEntryDetail`. In that case, you have to modify `private Long jvNumber` to `private JournalEntryDetail journalEntryDetail` and use the annotation `@OneToOne(mappedBy="jvNumber")` instead of `@OneToOne @Column(name="jv_number")`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@OneToOne` from `JournalEntryMaster` above `@Column(name="jv_number") private Long jvNumber` and relation of `JournalEntryDetail` with `JournalEntryMaster`
is `@ManyToOne` not `@OneToOne`. you give two relation together for one table in `JournalEntryDetail`

remove:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "jvnumber_fk", referencedColumnName = "jv_number")
@OneToOne(targetEntity = JournalEntryMaster.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private JournalEntryMaster jvNumber;
```

Here down modified code:

**JournalEntryMaster**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class JournalEntryMaster {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="jv_number")
private Long jvNumber;

@Column(name="jv_master_date")
private Date Date;

@Column(name="jv_reference_no")
private String ReferenceNo;

@Column(name="memo")
private String Memo;

@Column(name="posted")
private boolean Posted;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = JournalEntryDetail.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<JournalEntryDetail> journalEntryDetail = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**JourEntryDetail**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString

public class JournalEntryDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="account_number")
private Long accountNumber;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="jv_detail_drcr")
private DrOrCrSide DrCr;

@Column(name="amount")
private Double Amount;

@Column(name="memo")
private String Memo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "jv", referencedColumnName = "id")
private JournalEntryMaster jv;

@JoinColumn(name = "account_fk_jv", referencedColumnName = "account_number")
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Account.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Account account_number;
```